# How to navigate when multiple views share the same view model

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, prism, mef

I have a view that has a view model with a reasonably complex object structure. I want the user to be able to add a small amount of data to an entity on the viewmodel, and have created a second view which is to be navigated to in the same region as the first view. As there are very few requirements for the viewmodel of the additional view, it shares the same ViewModel as the inital view. On the click of a button I want to load the additional view, allow the user to enter some data which will update the viewmodel, and click an OK button that will then use the navigationservice to GoBack to the previous view. However the call to

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate(<regionname>, <viewname>
```

appears to do nothing. I have marked the ViewModel as NonShared and have put a breakpoint in the codebehind of the view, where the viewmodel is imported, but the breakpoint is never hit. What am I missing here? Or, is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve anyway?

Answer (score 0):

In PRISM - there is 2 navigation strategies. State-based navigation and view-based navigation. It sounds that what you doing can be State-based navigation and separate views not really needed.

However, nothing prevents you from doing what you want. I would just to test - try and put `NonShared` on views also. I'm pretty sure what you have is composition error. `RegionManager` does not throw exceptions, it swallows those by default. To really see what's going on - add event handler for RegionManager and see what exception you get. More details here: http://blogs.southworks.net/gmaliandi/2011/08/how-to-prevent-region-navigation-from-hiding-exceptions-in-prism/